# Flutter/Dart Data Class

Tags: android, json, laravel, flutter, dart

I'm building a self practice eCommerce app using flutter (my back-end is in Laravel). Every time I make a model class, I always come across the issues in fromMap methods.

Currently I cant store my api response to the order (orders and orderItems class is given below). Error says

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<num>' 
in type cast
```

here's how I am trying to save the api response

```
Orders orders = Orders(
      List.from(response.data)
          .map<OrderItem>((item) => OrderItem.fromMap(item))
          .toList(),
    );
```

**Orders Class**

```
class Orders {
  final List<OrderItem> orders;

  Orders(
    this.orders,
  );

  Orders copyWith({
    List<OrderItem>? orders,
  }) {
    return Orders(
      orders ?? this.orders,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'orders': orders.map((x) => x.toMap()).toList(),
    };
  }

  factory Orders.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Orders(
      List<OrderItem>.from(
        (map['orders'] as List<int>).map<OrderItem>(
          (x) => OrderItem.fromMap(x as Map<String, dynamic>),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Orders.fromJson(String source) =>
      Orders.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);

  @override
  String toString() => 'Orders(orders: $orders)';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant Orders other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return listEquals(other.orders, orders);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => orders.hashCode;
}
```

**OrderItems Class**

```
class OrderItem {
  final num id;
  final List<num> pid;

  OrderItem(
    this.id,
    this.pid,
  );

  OrderItem copyWith({
    num? id,
    List<num>? pid,
  }) {
    return OrderItem(
      id ?? this.id,
      pid ?? this.pid,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'pid': pid,
    };
  }

  factory OrderItem.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return OrderItem(
      map['id'] as num,
      List<num>.from(
        (map['pid'] as List<num>),
      ),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory OrderItem.fromJson(String source) =>
      OrderItem.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);

  @override
  String toString() => 'OrderItem(id: $id, pid: $pid)';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant OrderItem other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other.id == id && listEquals(other.pid, pid);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode ^ pid.hashCode;
}
```

Here's what the API response looks like

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "uid": "1",
    "pid": [
      1,
      2
    ],
    "created_at": "2022-07-16T10:34:51.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-16T10:34:51.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "uid": "1",
    "pid": "[2,3]",
    "created_at": "2022-07-16T12:19:15.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-16T12:19:15.000000Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: There is an issue on json of `pid` data type

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yeah. I tried without a subclass before but even that didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you don't want to define all these data class methods every time since it can be time consuming and error prone.

I recently created a package which can help you add all this functionality without being too intrusive on your models.  You can check it out at: https://pub.dev/packages/mint.

You can also use freezed (https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) which is an excellent package with a proven track record.  However, you may have to drastically change your coding style to be compatible with freezed.  This is my only issue with it.  Mint's primary purpose is to stay out of your way as much as possible.  It's also template driven so you can easily modify the templates and add your own functionality as you see fit.